# What does it mean when we say that the multiplication of two matrices is invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse-function

I'm trying to understand the concept of inverting matrices but this I don't understand much.

I know: a matrix $A$ is said to be invertible if there is a matrix $C$ such that: $CA=AC = I$ (where $I$ is the identity matrix).

But how does all of this relate together and what does it mean when we say that the multiplication of two matrices is invertible?

Please provide me with a written explanation because using only mathematical symbols and notations confuses me.

Comment: Well, for example $3$ is an invertible number, because there is another number, $1/3$, such that $3 \times \frac 13 = \frac 13 \times 3 = 1$. However, $0$ is not an invertible number because you cannot find a number $a$ satisfying $0 \times a =1$. Similar for matrices.

Comment: I have never heard the expression "multiplication of two matrices is invertible."  I have heard of matrices themselves being invertible.

Comment: Do you mean $AB$, the product of two matrices? If yes, then the meaning that $AB$ is invertible is just the same that it is for any matrix. You already wrote it: There is a matrix $C$ such that $ABC = CAB = I$.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to ploosu2's comment of "the product of two matrices is invertible", you may also be thinking of "multiplication by $A$ is an invertible operation". That is, if $A$ is invertible, and $BA = CA$, then $B = C$. We can "undo" multiplication by $A$.